Notify icon window won't exit program if hwnd set as foreground window
I have a notification icon app in zig using Win32 API. It has this code as its WndProc:
const std = @import("std");
const windows = std.os.windows;
const zeroes = std.mem.zeroes;

pub const WNDPROC = *const fn (
    hwnd: windows.HWND,
    uMsg: windows.UINT,
    wParam: windows.WPARAM,
    lParam: windows.LPARAM,
) callconv(windows.WINAPI) windows.LRESULT;

pub const WNDCLASSEXA = extern struct {
    cbSize: windows.UINT = @sizeOf(WNDCLASSEXA),
    style: windows.UINT,
    lpfnWndProc: WNDPROC,
    cbClsExtra: i32 = 0,
    cbWndExtra: i32 = 0,
    hInstance: windows.HINSTANCE,
    hIcon: ?windows.HICON,
    hCursor: ?windows.HCURSOR,
    hbrBackground: ?windows.HBRUSH,
    lpszMenuName: ?[*:0]const u8,
    lpszClassName: [*:0]const u8,
    hIconSm: ?windows.HICON,
};

pub const NOTIFYICONDATAW = extern struct {
    cbSize: windows.DWORD = @sizeOf(NOTIFYICONDATAW),
    hWnd: windows.HWND,
    uID: windows.UINT,
    uFlags: windows.UINT,
    uCallbackMessage: windows.UINT,
    hIcon: windows.HICON,
    szTip: [128]u8,
    dwState: windows.DWORD,
    dwStateMask: windows.DWORD,
    szInfo: [256]u16,
    DUMMYUNIONNAME: extern union {
        uTimeout: windows.UINT,
        uVersion: windows.UINT,
    },
    szInfoTitle: [64]u16,
    dwInfoFlags: windows.DWORD,
    guidItem: windows.GUID,
    hBalloonIcon: windows.HICON,
};

pub const MSG = extern struct {
    hWnd: ?windows.HWND,
    message: windows.UINT,
    wParam: windows.WPARAM,
    lParam: windows.LPARAM,
    time: windows.DWORD,
    pt: windows.POINT,
    lPrivate: windows.DWORD,
};

pub const HBITMAP = *opaque {};

pub const MENUITEMINFOW = extern struct {
    cbSize: windows.UINT = @sizeOf(MENUITEMINFOW),
    fMask: windows.UINT,
    fType: windows.UINT,
    fState: windows.UINT,
    wID: windows.UINT,
    hSubMenu: windows.HMENU,
    hbmpChecked: HBITMAP,
    hbmpUnchecked: HBITMAP,
    dwItemData: windows.ULONG_PTR,
    dwTypeData: windows.LPCWSTR,
    cch: windows.UINT,
    hbmpItem: HBITMAP,
};

pub const NIF_ICON = 0x00000002;
pub const NIF_INFO = 0x00000010;
pub const NIF_MESSAGE = 0x00000001;
pub const NIM_ADD = 0x00000000;
pub const NIM_DELETE = 0x00000002;
pub const SW_HIDE = 0;
pub const TPM_LEFTALIGN = 0x0000;
pub const TPM_NONOTIFY = 0x0080;
pub const TPM_RETURNCMD = 0x100;
pub const TPM_RIGHTBUTTON = 0x0002;
pub const WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;
pub const WM_COMMAND = 0x0111;
pub const WM_DESTROY = 0x0002;
pub const WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
pub const WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205;
pub const WM_USER = 0x0400;

pub extern "shell32" fn Shell_NotifyIconW(
    dwMessage: windows.DWORD,
    lpData: [*c]NOTIFYICONDATAW,
) callconv(windows.WINAPI) windows.BOOL;

pub extern "shell32" fn ExtractIconExA(
    lpszFile: windows.LPCSTR,
    nIconIndex: i32,
    phiconLarge: [*c]windows.HICON,
    phiconSmall: [*c]windows.HICON,
    nIcons: windows.UINT,
) callconv(windows.WINAPI) windows.UINT;

pub extern "user32" fn CreateWindowExA(
    dwExStyle: windows.DWORD,
    lpClassName: [*:0]const u8,
    lpWindowName: [*:0]const u8,
    dwStyle: windows.DWORD,
    X: i32,
    Y: i32,
    nWidth: i32,
    nHeight: i32,
    hWindParent: ?windows.HWND,
    hMenu: ?windows.HMENU,
    hInstance: windows.HINSTANCE,
    lpParam: ?windows.LPVOID,
) callconv(windows.WINAPI) ?windows.HWND;

pub extern "user32" fn PostQuitMessage(
    nExitCode: i32,
) callconv(windows.WINAPI) void;

pub extern "user32" fn DestroyWindow(
    hWnd: windows.HWND,
) callconv(windows.WINAPI) windows.BOOL;

pub extern "user32" fn GetWindowLongPtrA(
    hWnd: windows.HWND,
    nIndex: i32,
) callconv(windows.WINAPI) windows.LONG_PTR;

pub extern "user32" fn SetWindowLongPtrA(
    hWnd: windows.HWND,
    nIndex: i32,
    dwNewLong: windows.LONG_PTR,
) callconv(windows.WINAPI) windows.LONG_PTR;

pub extern "user32" fn DefWindowProcA(
    hWnd: windows.HWND,
    Msg: windows.UINT,
    wParam: windows.WPARAM,
    lParam: windows.LPARAM,
) callconv(windows.WINAPI) windows.LRESULT;

pub extern "user32" fn GetMessageA(
    lpMsg: *MSG,
    hWnd: ?windows.HWND,
    wMsgFilterMin: windows.UINT,
    wMsgFilterMax: windows.UINT,
) callconv(windows.WINAPI) windows.BOOL;

pub extern "user32" fn RegisterClassExA(
    *const WNDCLASSEXA,
) callconv(windows.WINAPI) windows.ATOM;

pub extern "user32" fn TranslateMessage(
    lpMsg: *const MSG,
) callconv(windows.WINAPI) windows.BOOL;

pub extern "user32" fn DispatchMessageA(
    lpMsg: *const MSG,
) callconv(windows.WINAPI) windows.LRESULT;

pub extern "user32" fn CreatePopupMenu() callconv(windows.WINAPI) windows.HMENU;

pub extern "user32" fn GetCursorPos(
    lpPoint: [*c]windows.POINT,
) callconv(windows.WINAPI) windows.BOOL;

pub extern "user32" fn SetForegroundWindow(
    hWnd: windows.HWND,
) callconv(windows.WINAPI) windows.BOOL;

pub extern "user32" fn TrackPopupMenu(
    hMenu: windows.HMENU,
    uFlags: windows.UINT,
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
    nReserved: i32,
    hWnd: windows.HWND,
    prcRect: [*c]const windows.RECT,
) callconv(windows.WINAPI) windows.BOOL;

pub extern "user32" fn InsertMenuItemW(
    hMenu: std.os.windows.HMENU,
    item: std.os.windows.UINT,
    fByPosition: std.os.windows.BOOL,
    lpmi: [*c]MENUITEMINFOW,
) callconv(std.os.windows.WINAPI) std.os.windows.BOOL;

fn registerClassExA(window_class: *const WNDCLASSEXA) !windows.ATOM {
    const atom = RegisterClassExA(window_class);
    if (atom != 0) return atom;
    switch (windows.kernel32.GetLastError()) {
        .CLASS_ALREADY_EXISTS => return error.AlreadyExists,
        .INVALID_PARAMETER => unreachable,
        else => |err| return windows.unexpectedError(err),
    }
}

fn createWindowExA(
    dwExStyle: u32,
    lpClassName: [*:0]const u8,
    lpWindowName: [*:0]const u8,
    dwStyle: u32,
    X: i32,
    Y: i32,
    nWidth: i32,
    nHeight: i32,
    hWindParent: ?windows.HWND,
    hMenu: ?windows.HMENU,
    hInstance: windows.HINSTANCE,
    lpParam: ?*anyopaque,
) !windows.HWND {
    const window = CreateWindowExA(dwExStyle, lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, X, Y, nWidth, nHeight, hWindParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam);
    if (window) |win| return win;
    switch (windows.kernel32.GetLastError()) {
        .CLASS_DOES_NOT_EXIST => return error.ClassDoesNotExist,
        .INVALID_PARAMETER => unreachable,
        else => |err| return windows.unexpectedError(err),
    }
}

pub fn createIconFromFile(path: [:0]const u8) !windows.HICON {
    var icon: windows.HICON = undefined;
    const ret = ExtractIconExA(
        path,
        0,
        null,
        &icon,
        1,
    );
    if (ret != 1) {
        return error.NotIcon;
    }
    return icon;
}

var isRunning = true;

fn ProcessIconMessage(hwnd: windows.HWND, _: windows.UINT, _: windows.WPARAM, lParam: windows.LPARAM, tray: *Tray) void {
    if (lParam == WM_LBUTTONUP) {
        _ = DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        isRunning = false;
    } else if (lParam == WM_RBUTTONUP) {
        var point: windows.POINT = undefined;
        _ = GetCursorPos(&point);
        _ = SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
        _ = TrackPopupMenu(tray.hmenu, TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON | TPM_RETURNCMD | TPM_NONOTIFY, point.x, point.y, 0, hwnd, null);
    }
}

fn WndProc(hwnd: windows.HWND, uMsg: windows.UINT, wParam: windows.WPARAM, lParam: windows.LPARAM) callconv(windows.WINAPI) windows.LRESULT {
    const tray_pointer = GetWindowLongPtrA(hwnd, 0);
    if (tray_pointer == 0) {
        return DefWindowProcA(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    const tray = @as(*Tray, @ptrFromInt(@as(usize, @intCast(tray_pointer))));
    switch (uMsg) {
        WM_CLOSE => {
            _ = DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        },
        WM_DESTROY => {
            _ = PostQuitMessage(0);
        },
        WM_TRAY_CALLBACK_MESSAGE => ProcessIconMessage(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam, tray),
        WM_COMMAND => ProcessIconMessage(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam, tray),
        else => return DefWindowProcA(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam),
    }

    return 0;
}

pub const ID_TRAY_FIRST = 1000;
pub const MFT_STRING = 0x00000000;
pub const WM_TRAY_CALLBACK_MESSAGE = WM_USER + 1;
pub const WC_TRAY_CLASS_NAME = "TRAY";

fn createMenu(id: *windows.UINT) windows.HMENU {
    const hmenu = CreatePopupMenu();
    {
        defer id.* += 1;
        var mitem = zeroes(MENUITEMINFOW);
        mitem.cbSize = @sizeOf(MENUITEMINFOW);
        mitem.fType = MFT_STRING;
        mitem.fState = 0;
        _ = InsertMenuItemW(hmenu, id.*, windows.TRUE, &mitem);
    }
    return hmenu;
}

pub const Tray = struct {
    wc: WNDCLASSEXA = zeroes(WNDCLASSEXA),
    hmenu: windows.HMENU = undefined,

    pub fn init(self: *Tray) !void {
        self.wc.cbSize = @sizeOf(WNDCLASSEXA);
        self.wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
        self.wc.cbWndExtra = @sizeOf(*Tray);
        self.wc.hInstance = @as(windows.HINSTANCE, @ptrCast(windows.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW(null)));
        self.wc.lpszClassName = WC_TRAY_CLASS_NAME;
        _ = try registerClassExA(&self.wc);
    }

    pub fn setupMenu(self: *Tray, _: windows.HWND, _: NOTIFYICONDATAW) !void {
        var id: windows.UINT = ID_TRAY_FIRST;
        self.hmenu = createMenu(&id);
    }
};

pub fn main() !void {
    var tray = Tray{};
    const icon = try createIconFromFile("icon.ico");
    try tray.init();

    // try create window
    const hwnd = try createWindowExA(0, WC_TRAY_CLASS_NAME, WC_TRAY_CLASS_NAME, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, null, tray.wc.hInstance, null);
    _ = SetWindowLongPtrA(hwnd, 0, @as(windows.LONG_PTR, @intCast(@intFromPtr(&tray))));
    const text = "Tray Icon";
    var szTip: [128]u8 = zeroes([128]u8); // Initialize the array to zeros

    // Copy the string literal into the fixed-size array
    std.mem.copyForwards(u8, &szTip, text);
    var nid: NOTIFYICONDATAW = zeroes(NOTIFYICONDATAW);
    nid.cbSize = @sizeOf(NOTIFYICONDATAW);
    nid.hWnd = hwnd;
    nid.uID = 1;
    nid.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_INFO;
    nid.uCallbackMessage = WM_TRAY_CALLBACK_MESSAGE;
    nid.hIcon = icon;
    nid.szTip = szTip;

    _ = Shell_NotifyIconW(NIM_ADD, &nid);

    try tray.setupMenu(hwnd, nid);

    while (isRunning) {
        var msg: MSG = undefined;
        _ = GetMessageA(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0);
        _ = TranslateMessage(&msg);
        _ = DispatchMessageA(&msg);
    }
}

The program will exit correctly if I just left-click on my app notification icon.
If I right-click first so it calls SetForegroundWindow(), then left-click, the icon is deleted from the notification area but the program doesn't exit, it just hangs there. If I Ctrl+C then the app exits properly.
I was expecting it to also just exit the program if I right-click before left-click.
This is the last few console output when just left clicking the icon where it quit properly
info: WndProc os.windows.HWND__opaque_2021@1b0d24 1025 1 512
info: Tray: 48926552960
info: WndProc os.windows.HWND__opaque_2021@1b0d24 1025 1 513
info: Tray: 48926552960
info: WndProc os.windows.HWND__opaque_2021@1b0d24 1025 1 514
info: Tray: 48926552960
info: WndProc os.windows.HWND__opaque_2021@1b0d24 144 0 0
info: Tray: 48926552960
info: WndProc os.windows.HWND__opaque_2021@1b0d24 2 0 0
info: Tray: 48926552960
info: WndProc os.windows.HWND__opaque_2021@1b0d24 130 0 0
info: Tray: 48926552960
  main
   ~\....\zig-notification-area
➜

And here is if I right click first
info: WndProc os.windows.HWND__opaque_2021@3a190e 1025 1 512
info: Tray: 149451435920
info: WndProc os.windows.HWND__opaque_2021@3a190e 1025 1 513
info: Tray: 149451435920
info: WndProc os.windows.HWND__opaque_2021@3a190e 1025 1 514
info: Tray: 149451435920
info: WndProc os.windows.HWND__opaque_2021@3a190e 144 0 0
info: Tray: 149451435920
info: WndProc os.windows.HWND__opaque_2021@3a190e 2 0 0
info: Tray: 149451435920
info: WndProc os.windows.HWND__opaque_2021@3a190e 130 0 0
info: Tray: 149451435920

It's almost identical except the app just stuck in there hanging not quitting the program, I'm expecting both of them result the program exit correctly

Are hwnd and tray.hwnd two different windows? Where are you creating and removing the icon? This is not a [mcve]. Why are you bringing the icon's callback window to the foreground in the first place? You should not be doing that unless you are about to display a popup menu, which this example is not doing.

@RemyLebeau I've updated the code to include the main app code, yes the right click is for showing up a menu, for now it's just an empty menu, but the problem is still the same, it exit properly when it's just left click, but it doesn't exit when right click first to show the menu and then left click

Maybe related, maybe not, but you need to call PostMessage(hwnd, WM_NULL, 0, 0); after TrackPopupMenu() returns. https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/135788

@RemyLebeau I've try adding _ = PostMessageA(hwnd, WM_NULL, 0, 0); after TrackPopupMenu and still result the same

Maybe I am missing something, but why this is tagged c?

@chrslg Because the win32 api is in c so I thought it might be related
